# write character buffer in Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a Bluetooth Low Energy supported application.
I will be communicating with a hardware device that supports a characterstic. Lets assume that the characteristic is defined as "TestCharacteristic".
Based on the scenario, I want to write different data to the same characteristic.

In my iOS app, i will have two buttons.

I want to send a character buffer of 20 byte on clicking the first button and different character buffer of 20 byte on clicking the second button.

OnButton 1 Click:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = Service  
            .getCharacteristic("TestCharacteristic");  
    if (charac == null) {  
        Log.e(TAG, "char not found!");  
        return false;  
    }  


    byte[20] value = {0xEF, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0xEF, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xEF, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0xEF, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xEF, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  
    charac.setValue(value);  
    boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(charac);
```

OnButton 2 Click:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = Service  
            .getCharacteristic("TestCharacteristic");  
    if (charac == null) {  
        Log.e(TAG, "char not found!");  
        return false;  
    }  


    byte[20] value = {0xDC, 0, 0, 0 ,0 , 0xDC, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0xDC, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0xDC, 0, 0, 0 ,0};  
    charac.setValue(value);  
    boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(chara  
c);
```

Is above operation possible?
Can I send different values for the same characteristic?

Thanks & Regards,
Phil

Comment: Of course you can, but not with that code.

Comment: Thank you Paulw11.

Can you tell me what do i need to change in the code?